# Delete method is not affecting the database if it's @Transactional

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions, modelmapper

I have this simple method to delete entries from the database.
It has worked fine until I added a @Transactional annotation.
In this case the finishes as usual but won't delete the object.

If I remove the @Transactional annotation or the ModelMapper it works as intended. (http://modelmapper.org/).
And I don't see any thrown exceptions which would explain a rollback to me

Please forgive me for ignoring some best practices in my code. I just

This is not working and won't affect the db.

```java
@Transactional
public JsonTrain delete(Long id) {
   Wagon wagon = wagonRepository.getOne(id);
   isSafeForDelete(wagon);
   wagonRepository.delete(wagon);
   return modelMapper.map(wagon.getTrain(), JsonTrain.class);
}
```

This is working:

```java
public JsonTrain delete(Long id) {
   Wagon wagon = wagonRepository.getOne(id);
   isSafeForDelete(wagon);
   wagonRepository.delete(wagon);
   return modelMapper.map(wagon.getTrain(), JsonTrain.class);
}
```

And this is working

```java
@Transactional
public void delete(Long id) {
   Wagon wagon = wagonRepository.getOne(id);
   isSafeForDelete(wagon);
   wagonRepository.delete(wagon);
}
```

I'm fine with the workaround but would like to understand the reason.

Thanks

Comment: Can you check what happens if you try to call `wagon.getTrain()` before  `wagonRepository.delete(wagon)`?

Comment: Just tried that with the same result.
The object will be deleted from the database

Comment: Looks like this happens when the modelmapper can't map a field of Train to JsonTrain

Comment: What kind o a relationship between Wagon and Train do you have? Eager or Lazy?

Comment: I see now that it must be eager because you can load train out of the transaction scope ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you marked as "working" leads to the hipothesis  that the Wagon - Train relationship is `fetch="EAGER"`

This "not working" and "one transaction" code:

```
@Transactional
public JsonTrain delete(Long id) {
   Wagon wagon = wagonRepository.getOne(id);
   isSafeForDelete(wagon);
   wagonRepository.delete(wagon);
   return modelMapper.map(wagon.getTrain(), JsonTrain.class);
}
```

first loads a wagon from repository (`Wagon wagon = wagonRepository.getOne(id)`), then mark it as removed (`wagonRepository.delete(wagon)`) see: [JPA entity lifecycle](https://dzone.com/articles/jpa-entity-lifecycle). Finally the Train  (`wagon.getTrain()`) reference is passed to modelmapper. Because of the hipothesis expressed at the beginning of my answer Train was loaded from database before the Wagon was removed. To remove a wagon you should try also remove it from Train wagons list.

The code you marked as "working" has a semantics where each repository operation is executed in separate transaction (`Wagon wagon = wagonRepository.getOne(id)` and `wagonRepository.delete(wagon)`). So when you pass the train to modelmapper the wagon is already deleted from database - but - because the wagon with train was loaded before deletion the removed wagon should also be mapped to JsonTrain (assuming that JsonTran has JsonWagon list :) ).

Comment: That's it.
I have to remove the wagon from the wagon list of the train object.
The fetch type is not specified (so lazy by default because of @OneToMany) but it seems to work with eager